# How to use Unique or Distinct in a CASE STATEMENT (SQL ORACLE)?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a CASE STATEMENT in SQL (Oracle) where I need to select only single rows in addition to other criteria.

I'm trying to do it this way:

```
SELECT 
     A.*
    ,D.*
    ,(CASE WHEN (A.COLUMN1 = D.COLUMN2) AND (D.COLUMN3 = 1) AND (DISTINCT A.COLUMN4) THEN 1
     ELSE 0
    END) AS COLUMN8
FROM TOTAL1 A
FULL OUTER JOIN TOTAL2 D
ON A.COLUMN4 = D.COLUMN4
```

However, I get an error:

> ORA-00936: expressão não encontrada
>   00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Erro na linha: 51 Coluna: 89

I've also tried using UNIQUE instead of DISTINCT, but it also does not work.

This is TOTAL1 table (I have just numbers):

[image]

And this TOTAL2 table (I have just numbers):

[image]

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Sample data would be really helpful here ^ ^

Comment: This is wrong: `... AND (DISTINCT A.COLUMN4) THEN ...`. What was your intention? DISTINCT should follow SELECT, immediately; you can't put it wherever *you* find it appropriate - follow the syntax rules. So, what about A.COLUMN4? It can't stand *alone* in the universe, you have to compare it to something.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add: The `CREATE TABLE` statements for the tables. Sample data for the tables as `INSERT INTO` statements. The expected result with the given sample data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can speculate that your intention is to find values of `A.COLUMN4` that only appear once.  If so, use window functions:

```
SELECT A.*, D.*,
     (CASE WHEN A.COLUMN1 = D.COLUMN2 AND
                D.COLUMN3 = 1 AND
                COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY A.COLUMN4) = 1
           THEN 1
           ELSE 0
      END) AS COLUMN8
FROM TOTAL1 A FULL OUTER JOIN
     TOTAL2 D
     ON A.COLUMN4 = D.COLUMN4;
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks!!